# Как правильно забрать cookies проставленные в тесте используя jsdom?

Tags: javascript

Я использую jsdom
В тесте я проставил cookies. Как правильно забрать cookies?
Если сделать так window.document.cookie я получаю только первое значение

```js
        const obj = new JSDOM(
            `<!DOCTYPE html><body>
                <script>
                    (function() {
                       window.document.cookie = 'param1=val1;param2=val2';
                    })();
                </script>
            </body>`,
            {
                 contentType: "text/html",
                 runScripts: "dangerously"
            }
        );

        // only param1=val1
        console.log( obj.window.document.cookie);
```

Comment: Куки надо ставить по отдельности.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Присваивайте по одной паре.

```
const obj = new JSDOM(
    `<!DOCTYPE html><body>
                <script>
                    (function() {
                       window.document.cookie = 'param1=val1';
                       window.document.cookie = 'param2=val2';
                    })();
                </script>
            </body>`,
    {
        contentType: "text/html",
        runScripts: "dangerously"
    }
);

// param1=val1; param2=val2
console.log(obj.window.document.cookie);
```

Точка с запятой используется для других целей - https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie